# Identification of a beetle found in a basement in Virginia, USA

Tags: species-identification

[image]

Beetle found in basement in Alexandria, VA, USA

Approximately 5cm (2 inches) in length.

Answer (score 2):

That is a female Eastern Hercules beetle. *Dynastes tityus* https://bugguide.net/node/view/4462 Family Scarabaeidae, Subfamily Dynastinae. One of the largest of the beetles in the South-East U.S.